widget Testing a dialog box
I am testing for dialog box which has a dropdown menu.
After the selection is made in the dowpdown menu , the save button is not visible to the test. How can I fix this please.
I get this error :

The following TestFailure was thrown running a test:
Expected: exactly one matching candidate
  Actual: _TextWidgetFinder:<Found 0 widgets with text "Save": []>
   Which: means none were found but one was expected


Code :
testWidgets('Edit Set dialog works correctly', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  await tester.pumpWidget(
    ProviderScope(
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: NewScreen(),
      ),
    ),
  );

  // Ensure the widget tree is fully built
  await tester.pumpAndSettle();

  // Tap 'Add Set' to add a new set
  await tester.tap(find.text('Add Set'));
  await tester.pumpAndSettle(); // Ensure the UI updates

  // Tap the edit icon for the first set
  await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.edit));
  await tester.pumpAndSettle();

  // Ensure the 'Edit Set' dialog is displayed
  expect(find.text('Edit Set'), findsOneWidget);

  // **Interact with the exercise dropdown** (String)
  await tester.tap(find.byType(DropdownButton<String>).first);
  await tester.pumpAndSettle(); // Ensure dropdown is open
  await tester.tap(find.text('Barbell').last);
  await tester.pumpAndSettle(); // Ensure selection is made

  // Tap 'Save' to save the edited set
  expect(find.text('Save'), findsOneWidget);
  await tester.tap(find.text('Save'));
  await tester.pumpAndSettle(); // Ensure the UI updates

  // // Verify that the set has been updated to 'Bench Press'
  expect(find.text('Barbell'), findsOneWidget);
});

If I comment out all the code in "Interact with the exercise dropdown" section , it then works fine . So "Save" is recognised as a text
